# What is the difference between "The saying is taken from a well-known American movie" & "This saying has been taken from a well-known American movie"

Tags: passive-voice

What is the difference between simple present passive voice [is+v3] and present perfect passive voice [has been+v3].
When to use them?

Comment: There's no difference. Nor would it mean anything different in most contexts if you'd used simple past *The saying **was** taken from a well-known American movie*.

Comment: When talking about a quotation, it's fine to say _is taken_. The words haven't literally been removed from the movie's dialogue. We would say "My bicycle has been taken from outside the house."